# How to open Vim in Terminator by default?

Tags: terminal, vim

I installed Terminator as the default terminal, you can see it in the screenshot.

But when I launch Vim through the menu it opens at the gnome-terminal.

I tried to change the settings in `gsettings`, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to change.

System: Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
Cinnamon version: 3.0.7
Terminator version: 0.98
VIM version: 7.4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Directly changing the value of the below 2 things in `/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop` file is solving this.

```
Exec=terminator -e "vim %F"
Terminal=false
```

If the `vim.desktop` file is not found in the shared location, try locating it with the help of `locate` command.

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to write down a little script to launch vim with terminator**

```
#!/bin/bash
terminator -e vim
```

Save it and run `chmod 754 /path/to/script`

**Now you need to find vim's `.desktop` file.** You can do it like this:

```
locate .desktop | grep vim
```

You may get several results, but go for the one `.desktop` stored at `/usr/share/applications`. It's typically just named `vim.desktop`.

**Open it so you can edit it with privileges:**

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/vim.desktop
```

**And edit the `Exec=` line so that it reads**

```
Exec=/path/to/script
```

---

Writing the script is necessary because having several `.desktop` pointing at the same executable (if we would just do `Exec= terminator -e vim`), can cause trouble.

Comment: I made the file and put it in `/home/id/bin`
`-rwxr-xr-- 1 id id  29 May 17 18:03 vim_run`

And edited the required file
`gksudo xed /usr/share/applications/vim.desktop`
`Exec=/home/id/bin/vim_run`     



But nothing has changed

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted the system

Comment: Did you try launching the script from terminal?

Comment: Yes, it runs Vim in Terminator in another window
And shows a warning

Comment: `Warning: python-keybinder is not installed. This means the hide_window shortcut will be unavailable
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'`

Comment: Open /usr/share/applications with a file browser and drag the vim `.desktop` you edited to the launcher.

Comment: Now after launch opens two terminals gnome-terminal and terminator. And in gnome-terminal there is a error: “`PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'`”

Answer (score 0):

[Becerra's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365596/105997) worked for me only with some modifications ...

1. You need to write a script with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   terminator -e "vim $1"
   ```
2. In my case the desktop file Becerra mentioned wasn't stored at `/usr/share/applications` but at `$HOME/.local/share/applications`
3. In the vim.desktop file I had to change the `Exec`and the `Terminal` command as follows:

   ```
   Exec=/path/to/script %F
   Terminal=false
   ```